# MongoDB fetch from remote API if document not found

Tags: javascript, mongodb

We're in the process of rebuilding our current Customer Portal from scratch.  Our current portal has a bunch of cron jobs which sync all of our client, contact, and invoice records from our WHMCS billing system, but this is a really horrible way to do it.  One of our developers has suggested using MongoDB to cache the data pulled via the WHMCS API, which would work nicely, but he also suggested that he remembered having setup MongoDB so that if a find by ID didn't result in a page, it would trigger a javascript routine on MongoDB to go and make the API call to fetch the required record.

That sounded fantastic, however after many hours of googling and reading through MongoDB documentation, I can't for the life of me find a way to do this on the MongoDB side.  We coudl do it fairly easily from the PHP side (Especially since we're using Yii2), but it would be a very clean solution to do it from the MongoDB side..

Hoping perhaps someone has come across such a use case, and can provide an example of doing it from MongoDB?

Comment: This sounds like it should be implemented on top of mongodb, not within

Comment: That's a good point. You just gave me a brainwave. - we're already accessing WHMCS through a helper object.. We'll just add the caching calls right into the object - if its in the cache, we return the cached object.  Otherwise fetch, cache, and return.   Not quite as cool as having it automated through mongo, but it'll do!

Comment: I think that's a lot cooler: the next developer (which may be you in a few months) will find the caching code where he'll expect it

Comment: @VK2TDG how did this work out for you? Is your cached API help object in Git anywhere? I'm doing something similar, where I want to grab a doc from the local MongoDB first, and get it from the API if not found.

Comment: @MichaelBlackburn We actually ended up adding triggers to almost all the tables in the WHMCS MySQL database to pop table name, primary key, and operation (insert/update/delete) into a 'queue' table.  We then poll this table at least once a second, and fetch all the operations, plus associated data (so insert into tblhosting would mean we select from tblhosting where id=queue.pkid), and then push it into a JMS queue.  We then have a listener on that JMS queue which pushes all updates into mongodb as updates with 'upsert=true' (or delete if it's a delete).  That's working VERY nicely.